# Alternative for webviews evaluateJavascript function for API before KitKat

Tags: android, webview

I need to get the content of the displayed data in a `WebView` at some state different then after loading the page (the user has to scroll down to load more content). This means, `WebViewClient` `onPageFinished` function does not work for me...

My function looks like following:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private void parsePage()
{
    webview.evaluateJavascript(
            "(function() { return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML; })();",
            new ValueCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onReceiveValue(String html) {
                    // handle html content...
                }
            });
}
```

Does anyone know an alternative solution for APIs before KitKat?